# Error when Updating SharePoint Form

Tags: infopath, error, forms-services

I have a form that can be edited in SharePoint 2010 when users submit a request. To clarify, it's not the form implementation they are editing, it is the fields in the form that they are editing. The form is associated with a SharePoint list. The form allows users to submit requests for tasks. User's can also update / modify requests. The form was built in InfoPath by someone else. The problem is that when some users update the form, they get an error message and other users do not. The set of users who do not get the error message, never get it. The set of users who do get the error message when updating the form, always get it. The error is this:

```
An error occurred querying a data source.

Click OK to resume filling out the form. You may want to check your form data for errors.

Error details
An error occurred while trying to connect to a Web service.
An entry has been added to the Windows event log of the server. Log ID:5566.

Correlation ID:14faba0e-0844-46c3-b74f-d257aed242f8
```

The same rights and access has been given to both set of users, those who get the error and those who don't.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem can be or what I can do to investigate?

Please note I do not have access to Central Admin, the server, or log files.

Comment: What data sources is the InfoPath form querying? How is your form filling in those query values? If possible, you should work towards getting access to the log files, since that would be very helpful in determining the cause of this (and other) errors.

Comment: In the end, it is 2015 when this was sent, but when you mentioned InfoPath, It's actually pretty likely the calls you make to get information from SharePoint, or using a People Picker to query Profile information from SharePoint, that these people may have Apostrophes. This can cause problems.